# save google registration id to database phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

Hi hello i m new to phonegap i want to implement notification so  i have used 
    cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git to implement , 
    now i m getting     Registration id and success status OK but   i want to store that REG_id 
    for my future purpose
    i have used ajax post method as soon as we get register id but i m not able to post  please
     help    me

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery_1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     var pushNotification;

      function onLoad() {
         document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      }

    function onDeviceReady(){

        pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

        if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ){

        pushNotification.register(
            successHandler,
            errorHandler, {
                "senderID":"1234560",
                "ecb":"onNotificationGCM"
            });

        }

    }
    // Android
    function onNotificationGCM(e) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

        switch( e.event )
        {
        case 'registered':
            if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
            {

                        $.ajax({
                        url: "http://abcd.com/store.php",
                        context: document.body,
                      cache : false,
                      data: {
                           username : e.regid,
                      },
                      success: function ( data ) {
                        alert("regID  success");
                     }
               });

                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED ID is : -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                    console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
            }
            break;

        case 'message':
            if ( e.foreground )
            {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+e.soundname);
                my_media.play();
            }
            else
            { 
                if ( e.coldstart )
                {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                }
            }

            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
        break;

        case 'error':
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
        break;

        default:
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received
         and we do not know what it is</li>');
        break;
      }
    }

    function successHandler (result) {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success ID:'+ result +'</li>');



    }
    function errorHandler (error) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
    }

</script>
    <title>com.PhoneGap.c2dm</title>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">

    <div id="home">
        <div id="app-status-div">
            <ul id="app-status-ul">
                <li>Cordova PushNotification Plugin Demo</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Why are you unable to post? Did you get an error? Please elaborate